# deployng django in Apache mod_wsgi (embedded mode)

Tags: django, apache

I use Apache in Embedded mode as my production server.

whenever I make some modifications to my django core files (`urls.py`, `settings.py`, `views.py`, etc), I simply `touch` project.wsgi file and changes appear on the webpage instantly. Sometimes it works.

However sometimes it doesn't. Apache just hangs. It cannot serve requests and needs a restart (giving the users for 1-2 seconds an "Internal Server Error" message). Then I need to restart (restart, actually doesn't work too. It needs to stop and start again).

I am pasting some code from my `httpd.conf`

```
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 5
WSGIDaemonProcess myproject processes=4 threads=12 python-path=[...]
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
```

Why is that? Is it because Apache sometime it uses all processes at the same time and cannot reload core files? (this is what 'touch' should do, right?)

EDIT: I am sorry. Apache runs in embedded mode. My mistake. I updated the question.

EDIT2: Included `WSGIProcessGroup` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touching the WSGI script file doesn't do anything in embedded mode, so not surprising it doesn't work all the time. When it appears to, it is just that the request got handled by a new Apache process that hadn't handled requests before.

For touching the WSGI script file to work you need to use daemon mode. Your configuration is half broken though. You have define WSGIDaemonProcess for daemon mode, but then aren't delegating the application to run under that daemon process group using WSGIProcessGroup.

Go read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to delete `*.pyc` files, as this will force a refresh. However the *real* answer to your problem is a proper deployment strategy so you don't end up doing development on your production server.

If you are using this server for django-only, may I suggest [nginx+uwsgi](http://www.jeremybowers.com/blog/post/5/django-nginx-and-uwsgi-production-serving-millions-page-views/) or [nginx+gunicorn](http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/) setup. This isolates your web environment from your backend allowing you to freely restart the wsgi processes without affecting your server. It also allows you to display a nice downtime page.

Comment: Thank you. However I am sorry I made a mistake. Apache runs in Embedded mode. Is your suggestion to delete `*.pyc` files still valid? Also, to be honest I am not into "administering" that much. I am considering gunicorn because I think it is easier to install. But at the moment I am keeping Apache? :-)